# Pass extra arguments to PyQt slot without losing default signal arguments

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

A PyQt button event can be connected in the normal way to a function so that the function receives the default signal arguments (in this case the button checked state):

```
def connections(self):
    my_button.clicked.connect(self.on_button)

def on_button(self, checked):
    print checked   # prints "True"
```

Or, the default signal arguments can be overridden using `lambda`:

```
def connections(self):
    my_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_button('hi'))

def on_button(self, message):
    print message   # prints "hi"
```

Is there a nice way to keep both signal arguments so it can be directly received by a function like below?

```
def on_button(self, checked, message):
    print checked, message   # prints "True, hi"
```

Comment: You can subclass the button and create a new signal which will emit the state of a button and a message.

Comment: [Eli Bendersky](https://eli.thegreenplace.net) posted [an article about this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/25/passing-extra-arguments-to-pyqt-slot) in 2011.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your `lambda` could take an argument:

```
def connections(self):
    my_button.clicked.connect(lambda checked: self.on_button(checked, 'hi'))

def on_button(self, checked, message):
    print checked, message   # prints "True, hi"
```

Or you could use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
# imports the functools module
import functools 

def connections(self):
    my_button.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.on_button, 'hi'))

def on_button(self, message, checked):
    print checked, message   # prints "True, hi"
```

Comment: This answer never gets old. It keeps saving me. Thanks!